# Why the css with less specificity take place

Tags: css

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#wo{
    color: red;
}

p{
    color: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wo">
<p>Hi</p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code. I declare the properties of id wo which has more high specificity in css(0,1,0,0) than the p(0,0,0,1) so why my paragraph shows yellow color?

Comment: Because `div`s are not paragraphs.....

Answer (score 3):

Because `Hi` is inside the `p` element, not inside `div#wo`. The `p` element is only indirectly influenced by the `#wo` rule through inheritance, but the `p` rule targets the `p` element directly, hence it overwrites inherited properties.

Specificity only applies if two rules match the same element, which is not your case.